# Need to flatten multiple tuples from a bag

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have input like this:

```
100.101.74.22   {(1358308803000,start,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23),(1358308973000,stop,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23),(1358308843000,pause,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23)}
```

I have written a script like this:

```
A = load 'inputpath' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (f1 : chararray, B:bag{T:tuple(x1 : chararray, x2 : chararray, x3 : chararray, x4 : chararray)});

B = foreach A generate f1,flatten(B.(x1, x2,x3,x4));
```

I am expecting output as:

```
100.101.74.22,1358308803000,start,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23,1358308973000,stop,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23,1358308843000,pause,100.101.74.22,http://server1.com/flvplay-1.26.swf%23
```

How can I get that? Please help.